# Dumb rbind for data.frames of different length

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I don't need any **smart** `rbind`, like `rbindlist`, `rbind.fill`, `bind_row` and other.

I need a dumb `rbind` to simply bind two dataframes:

```
> a <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
> b <- data.frame(b = 1:2)

> some.magic.bind(a, b) # what function to use here?

   a  b
1  1 1
2  2 2
3  3 NA
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `cbind` not `rbind`.

Try :

```
a = c(1:3)
b = c(1:2)

length(b) = length(a)

cbind(a, b)
```

Answer (score 5):

`merge` works directly on two `data.frame`s of different length and will keep it as a `data.frame`:

```
merge(a,b,by="row.names",all.x=TRUE)[,-1]
  a  b
1 1  1
2 2  2
3 3 NA
```